# Function sort an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, numbers

I have to write a function, which sorts an array containing numbers and strings.
For example:

```
uSort([3,"2", 4,1,"a","c","b"])  // -> ["a","b","c",1,"2",3, 4].
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
function uSort(arrayOfChars){
    var array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfChars.length; i++) { 
        if (typeof(arrayOfChars[i]) === '' ){ 
            array.unshift(arrayOfChars[i]); }
        else { 
            array.push(arrayOfChars[i]);
        };   
    }; 
    return array.sort();
};
```

But the result is wrong:

```
uSort([3,"2", 4,1,"a","c","b"])  // -> [1,"2",3, 4,"a","b","c"].
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code right now.

Comment: So strings before numbers ?

Comment: That's right adeneo.

Comment: `typeof` will never return `''`.

Comment: You should not be unsifting an array you are sorting, moving them to the end will make ZERO difference when you sort after it.

Comment: I've also tried typeof(arrayOfChars[i]) === 'string', but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to write your own custom sort method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to do that would be to just split the array into two arrays, one containing numbers and strings that are numbers, using `isNaN`, and one array containing everything else, then sort them and join them back together

```
function uSort(arrayOfChars){
    var numbs = arrayOfChars.filter(function(item) { return isNaN(item) });
    var chars = arrayOfChars.filter(function(item) { return !isNaN(item) });

    return numbs.sort().concat( chars.sort() );
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/umdqh54z/)

For better sorting of integers and special characters, you can add callbacks to the sorting

```
function uSort(arrayOfChars){
    var numbs = arrayOfChars.filter(function(item) { return !isNaN(item) });
    var chars = arrayOfChars.filter(function(item) { return isNaN(item) });

    return chars.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }).concat( numbs.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a == b ? 1 : a - b;
    }));
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/umdqh54z/4/)

Comment: You will still have to implement better number sorting, add a 10 anywhere and it will look like this `["a", "b", "c", 1, 10, "2", 3, 4]`

Comment: The string digits should be after the number ["a","b","c",1,"1",2,"2","2",3,"3"], instead got: ["a","b","c","1",1,"2",2,"2",3,"3"]

Comment: Seems weird you would do all of that when one sort method with a couple of checks works just as well.

Comment: @epascarello - at least it doesn't return `["a", "c", "b", ...]` like yours ?

Comment: @Dennis - modified the last one to do that as well.

Comment: The second function is pretty understandable and has the localeCompare which is good after like IE 11

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom comparator function which checks if the arguments are numeric with `isNaN` and then uses numerical or lexicographic sort:

```
[3, "2", 4, 1, "a", "c", "b"].sort(function(a,b) {
  if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    if(!isNaN(a)) return +1;              // Place numbers after strings
    if(!isNaN(b)) return -1;              // Place strings before numbers
    return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? +1 : 0); // Sort strings lexicographically
  }
  return a - b;                           // Sort numbers numerically
}); // ["a", "b", "c", 1, "2", 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your own custom sort method.

```
[3,"2", 4,1,"a","c","b"].sort( function (a,b) { 
    var sa = isNaN(a);
    var sb = isNaN(b);
    if(sa && sb) { //If both are strings, than compare
        return sa>sb; 
    } else if (!sa && !sb) {  //if both are numbers, convert to numbers and compare
        return Number(a) - Number(b);
    } else {  //if we have a number and a string, put the number last.
        return sa ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: also, you don't need to explicitly convert to Number if both are not `NaN`.

Comment: It was supposed to be `>` @Oriol

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to have numbers before letters (if this is your problem).

If you want to have letters before you have different ways.

One way is to order elements into two arrays (one for letters and one for numbers), then to merge them in the order you need.

Another way is to move the numbers at the end.

This is an example:
    alert((uSort([3,"2", 4,10,"a","c","b"])))  // -> ["a","b","c",1,"2",3, 4].

```
function uSort(arrayOfChars){
    var arrayNum = [];
    var arrayLet = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfChars.length; i++) { 
        if (typeof(arrayOfChars[i]) === '' ){ 
            array.unshift(arrayOfChars[i]); }
        else if (typeof(arrayOfChars[i]) === 'number' ){ 
            arrayNum.push(arrayOfChars[i]);
        } else {
            arrayLet.push(arrayOfChars[i]);
        }
    }; 

    if (arrayNum.size!=0 && arrayLet.size!=0) {
        arrayNum = arrayNum.sort(sortNumber);
        arrayNum.push();
        return arrayNum.concat(arrayLet.sort());
    } else if (arrayNum.size!=0) {
        return arrayNum.sort(sortNumber);
    } else {
        return arrayLet.sort();
    }


};

function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

Comment: True, but techically `"2"` isn't a number so you will have to add type casting as well

Comment: Yes, that's why I've used array.unshift to put the numbers at the end, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: There is no reason to do that and adding two arrays does not produce an array. That is totally wrong

Comment: This doesn't work. In example `uSort([3,"2", 4,1, 10,"a","c","b"])` returns `1,10,3,42,a,b,c`

Comment: it's wrong just the last line (that creates a string)... btw the other is correct... you need just to use concat()